# Создание плагина для Jira на python, javaScript или php

Tags: php, javascript, python, jira

Возможно ли создать плагин для Jira на python, javaScript или php без использование java?

Comment: Посмотрите на [http://www.jython.org/](jython), может быть не совсем то, что вы хотели...

Comment: * http://www.jython.org/

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какой плагин. В любом случае его надо будет оформлять в виде jar архива. 
В принципе, код можно писать на любом языке, который потом можно превратить в class файлы и выполнить на JVM. Т.е. снаружи минимальная обертка из Java понадобится скорее всего. А внутри пишите на чем хотите. Например. если пишете гаджет - то там может быть несколько примитивных строк на Java - а остальное на JavaScript. Т.е. Java минимально нужна как "коробка".

Ради интереса делал плагин для использования в Confluence языка Оберон-07 https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221676/obermacros. Там внутри код на языке Оберон-07 компилируется в JavaScript. Ну и все это упаковано в единый jar файл для загрузки плагина с минимальным количеством java кода. Код плагинов в Jira очень похож на код плагинов для Confluence.

Так что экспериментируйте - возьмите любой язык, который может работать поверх JVM и попробуйте. В любом случае будет интересный опыт.